# Fortran - Jump other subroutine

Tags: fortran, subroutine

I am trying to jump other subroutine in Fortran code. I used the **return** function but it is not working in some cases. Is there any way to jump to other subroutine. I made a simple example to define the problem. If the condition is in the same subroutine, I can use **goto label** but I need to jump different subroutine. If the condition is correct **(case = .True.)**, I don't want to calculate that subroutine so I will skip that subroutine, I will start to use the new data. For example, if `i=3 and case=true`, the program shouldn't print a=8 in the 3rd loop and jump the do loop in subroutine abc.

```
---------------------------------------------- 
subroutine abc()

do i=1, 5

 !if case is true, start to program from here.
 call vector ()
end do
end subroutine
-------------------------------------
subroutine vector()
if (case = .True.)then
 *****JUMP call vector in main program *****
 print *,"skip and jump "
 return
 a= 8
 print *, a 
 else
 b= 9
 print *, b
 print *, "continue the process "
 end if
end subroutine
------------------------------------------------

 -----output should be-------
 9
 9
 skip and jump
 9
 9
```

Comment: What problem do you have, not clear to me, do you want to return to the calling routine (abc) or back to another point? There are some "problems" in your "pseudo code: 1) where do you get the 'case' from 2) the = .True. is not necessary a boolean can directly be used in an `if` clause otherwise use .eqv. 3) I think the `end if` should be one line up as now the `print` is still part of the `if` clause and never reached due to the `return`.

Comment: Do you mean that if `case` is false you simply want to exit the subroutine and return, in your example, to `abc` ?  It would help us to help you if you had posted a [mcve].

Comment: @albert I just want  if condition is correct, should jump the `call vector()` in subroutine abc().

Comment: Basic part looks OK but points 1) and 2) remain. I would implement it differently (but this is depending on the case one works on). I would in the routine `abc` change the `call vector` to `if (.not. case) call vector` at least when it is known where `case` comes from.

Comment: @albert if (.not. case) not important i just write an example that is it. and I updated the question and gave example

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark if case is correct i want to exit the on that condition but continue the calculation because it is in do loop

Comment: Point 1), 2) still valid. statement a=8 etc. never reached as blocked by `return`

Comment: If anything I find the edited question *more* confusing than the earlier version !  Please try to write a [mcve], what you've posted is so broken it's almost useless for illustrating your problem.  Try also to edit your question with all the important information, don't rely on people reading a long series of comments and trying to figure it all out.

Comment: Thanks guys! I found the problem return function is enough for this case